# how to fix Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following sql server cursor insert to the table with variable out side from the cursor select as following,

```
DECLARE @Create_UserId uniqueidentifier,
        @Create_Date datetime,
        @Modification_UserId uniqueidentifier,
        @Modification_Date datetime,

SET @Create_UserId = '535EFDB6-CA05-4DB3-A379-E3D65CF9C08F';
SET @Create_Date = '2017-05-16 08:51:10.080';
SET @Modification_UserId = '535EFDB6-CA05-4DB3-A379-E3D65CF9C08F';
SET @Modification_Date = '2017-06-29 17:06:20.103';

DECLARE insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor CURSOR FOR
select 
CompanyID,APOD_Master_Id,APOD_Project_Id,APOD_Item_Num,APOD_Project_Code, APOD_Item_Id,apod_cost_centre_id
from Account_APOrderDetail aod
where aod.APOD_Master_Id in (
select ref_code
from Account_APOrderMaster
where apo_order_id = 00122975

);
OPEN insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor INTO
....
```

but when I run query I got following error

> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have missing variables for your cursor.

```
DECLARE @Create_UserId uniqueidentifier,
        @Create_Date datetime,
        @Modification_UserId uniqueidentifier,
        @Modification_Date datetime,

SET @Create_UserId = '535EFDB6-CA05-4DB3-A379-E3D65CF9C08F';
SET @Create_Date = '2017-05-16 08:51:10.080';
SET @Modification_UserId = '535EFDB6-CA05-4DB3-A379-E3D65CF9C08F';
SET @Modification_Date = '2017-06-29 17:06:20.103';

--variables
DECLARE 
    @CompanyID INT,
    @APOD_Master_Id INT,
    .....

DECLARE insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor CURSOR FOR
    select 
        CompanyID, APOD_Master_Id, APOD_Project_Id, APOD_Item_Num, APOD_Project_Code, APOD_Item_Id, apod_cost_centre_id
    from Account_APOrderDetail aod
    where aod.APOD_Master_Id in (
        select ref_code
        from Account_APOrderMaster
        where apo_order_id = 00122975
    )
OPEN insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor INTO @CompanyID, @APOD_Master_Id...
```

Comment: I need to know how to access SET variables like @Create_UserId,@Create_Date,@Modification_UserId,@@Modification_Date in the cursor